# Matrix class: "No instance of overloaded function push_back matches the argument list"

Tags: c++, matrix

So, I'm creating a class that represents an arbitrarily-sized matrix, and I want to write a function that "exports" the internal Vector to a 2-dimensional array.

I've found [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776224/4819461) that seems to do what I want. Here is what the code looks in my class:

```
// Export matrix to array
double** Matrix::a_data() const
{
    vector<double*> ptrs;
    for (auto& vec : mat) 
    {
        ptrs.push_back(vec.data());
    }
    return ptrs.data();
}
```

where *mat* is the vector < vector < double > > used to store the matrix's entries.

The post in question stated that *vec* needed to be an auto& instead of an auto because it is "very important to prevent vec from being a temporary copy."

However, in Visual Studio I'm always getting an error "no instance of overloaded function push_back matches the argument list... argument types are (const double*)"

So, my question is, how can I get this to work without changing auto& to auto? Also, how would one extend this to 3 dimensions?

Comment: Bigger problem: `ptrs.data()` is a dangling pointer as soon as `ptrs` is destroyed, which happens when `a_data()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a `const` problem.

Assuming `mat` is of type `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, `vec` will be of type `std::vector<double> const&` in the function. The `data()` member function for `const` objects returns `const*`, not a regular pointer.

Hence, you need to use:

```
vector<double const*> ptrs;
```

But then, using

```
return ptrs.data();
```

is going to cause bigger problems. `ptrs` is function local variable. It is going to be destructed when the function returns. Hence, the returned pointer will be a dangling pointer.

Options to overcome that problem.

1. Change the return type to `std::vector<double const*>`.
2. Create a dynamic array of `double const**` and return it.

I strongly recommend the first option.

Comment: So after changing "vector < double* >" to "vector < double const* >" I'm getting another error: "return value type does not match the function type"